# How do you get an image background on repeat to stay in the round border in a table on chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

There seems to be an issue with Chrome in this very specific way. If you have a table (yeah, I know tables are bad) with a border with rounded corners, and background image on repeat, then the image overflows the borders at the corners.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdfstrom/5cuRH/) example. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdfstrom/8f7Hu/) of what I expect to happen using a div instead of a table.

This only seems to happen in Google Chrome, not Safari, Firefox, Opera, or even Chromium. Adding `overflow: hidden;` does not fix it.

Is this a Chrome bug or is there something I am doing wrong that just happens to work on other webkit browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens but `display: inline-block` seems to fix it:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #CC6633;
    background-image:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42944578/gradient.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5cuRH/1/)

Comment: this is a good turn around. except you loose break lines before and after as block-element-levels do.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick and it doesn't appear to break anything else. Still doesn't explain why it fixes it...

Comment: it just get rids of <table>/display:table + border-radius issue when basicly border-spacing is not set to 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/8f7Hu/1/

Use css:

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with common bug of border-radius and <table>, Divs do not have specifity to be sized from the content they are holding.

Comment: Well, I need the y direction to be flexible so I can't repeat-y.

Comment: Right, but then the image repeats in the y direction and I don't want that

Comment: Increase border to 2px pixels, fixes the issue http://jsfiddle.net/8f7Hu/3/
Also, You should use gradient property instead of image, if you are going to use this image

Answer (score 0):

You may use border-spacing:0;

For Chrome , it seems not enough.
so we had :
overflow:hidden; and  declare background last (and not background-image.)

Other way, put background-image in tbody (even if you did not mark it , browsers generates it )

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5cuRH/3/

```
#placeholder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid #CC6633;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-spacing:0;
    background:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42944578/gradient.jpg);
}
table + table {background:none;}
table + table tbody {
   background-image:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42944578/gradient.jpg);
}
```